# Facebook graph API returns error 404

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm seeing a strange error calling FB graph API with a valid token. 
This is in the context of a Cordova angular JS application. 
I use $cordovaOAuth.facebook to login and that succeeds and I get back the access token. 
Then the code fetches some public profile details: image, name, location and gender like so:
 
$http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me', {params: {access_token: [token obtained from $cordovaOAuth.facebook() call],fields: "name,gender,location,picture", format: "json" }}....); 
This returns error 404 
In chrome://inspect the URL appears as https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?access_token=[token]&fields=name,gender,picture&format=json
When this URL is used in a browser it returns valid JSON response with all requested fields. 
 
Any ideas why this does not work in the cordova app?
NOTE. This used to work before. No changes on the app or Facebook back end.
Thank you
Andy

Comment: API v2.2 was shut down March 25, 2017, you should be using at least v2.4, because that is the currently lowest available one. Normally it should upgrade to that implicitly when you make requests to a lower API version, but perhaps that fails under certain conditions.

Comment: My problem turned out to be the $http angular service. Apparrnetly it requires cordova-plugin-whitelist. When I added it  everything works great now. Thank you for the tip on v 2.4

Comment: Did you had to configure something with the cordova-plugin-whitelist ?

Comment: Yes whitelist and in-app browser plugin  are required for this facebook plugin